# Imprimir un valor de forma aleatoria dentro de una matriz en Python

Tags: python

estoy haciendo el snake en python, y no se como insertar la fruta(*) de forma aleatoria dentro de mi tablero(que la hice con lista de listas) usando la función random.
el tablero vacio lo estoy imprimiendo asi, ingresando por parametro una matriz.

```
def imprimir(m):
    for fila in m:
        for col in fila:
            print(col,end=" ")
        print()
```

gracias

Comment: Lo que tienes que hacer es crear un par de números aleatorios, `x` e `y`, cada uno de ellos comprendido entre 0 y el número de columnas (o filas respectivamente) que serían las "coordenadas" donde iría la fruta. Éstos puedes generarlos con `random.randint()`. Una vez generados esos números, `m[x][y] = "*"` cambiaría el valor de ese elemento del tablero por un asterisco. La misma función que tienes para mostrar el tablero, lo mostraría ahora con "manzana incluida".

Comment: Gracias. Lo intente hacer así, pero al momento de imprimirlo, me imprime "*" en toda la columna. Donde debería ponerlo para que me aparezca en un solo lugar?